# nable to create certificate for Kubernetes web-app. cert-manager/challenges: propagation check failed" err="wrong status code '503', expected '200'"

Tags: kubernetes, web, https, kubernetes-ingress, cert-manager

I am working on deploying my app in k8s cluster. So, I decided to enable https connection to my application. I've created DNS name on the web-site Noip and connected it with the IP of my k8s cluster.
After that, I deployed cert-manager, ClusterIssuer, Certificate and then Ingress.

So, after applying a certificate i have the issue. Here are some logs of the pod of certificate-manager:

```
I0629 13:50:39.836830 1 service.go:45] "cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureService: found one existing HTTP01 solver Service for challenge resource" resource_name="cert-pd292-3618130802-4138407347" resource_namespace="default" resource_kind="Challenge" resource_version="v1" dnsName="nodeart.bounceme.net" type=HTTP-01 related_resource_name="cm-acme-http-solver-k2vs5" related_resource_namespace="default" related_resource_kind="" related_resource_version=""
I0629 13:50:39.836965 1 ingress.go:99] "cert-manager/challenges/http01/selfCheck/http01/ensureIngress: found one existing HTTP01 solver ingress" resource_name="cert-pd292-3618130802-4138407347" resource_namespace="default" resource_kind="Challenge" resource_version="v1" dnsName="nodeart.bounceme.net" type=HTTP-01 related_resource_name="cm-acme-http-solver-56pdn" related_resource_namespace="default" related_resource_kind="Ingress" related_resource_version="v1"
E0629 13:50:39.840308 1 sync.go:190] "cert-manager/challenges: propagation check failed" err="wrong status code '503', expected '200'" resource_name="cert-pd292-3618130802-4138407347" resource_namespace="default" resource_kind="Challenge" resource_version="v1" dnsName="nodeart.bounceme.net" type=HTTP-01
```

I've expected to see that i can connect to my web-app via browser using https but instead of this I get an error, that my site is not secure.